# How to deserialize Json with fix named elements dynamically in vb.net?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, httpclient

I’m on the way to implement an interface to the Ameritrade Rest API in a vb.net application (with httpclient).
Amongst other things, I have to query quotes from a ticker list (e.g. AMD,MSFT,AMZN, ....).
The call of the API works without problems, I get a valid Json back, but the Json is not given back in a way, I would expect.
I now search the best way to handle that problem...

This is not the first interface to a Rest API, I have implemented.
Normally, I implement a corresponding data class in vb.net and then use **JsonConvert** (from Newtonsoft) to deserialize the Json string into my data class.
Example:

```
 Dim oObject As New DataClass
 oObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataClass)(JsonString)
```

whereby DataClass is the vb.net class that is defined according to the data in the Json string.

**Problem:**
The ticker symbol-list to query is **dynamic** and can change from api call to api call.
If I - e.g. - query AMD and MSFT in a call, I get back (cut to only a few fields) the following Json:

```
{
  "AMD": {
    "assetType": "EQUITY",
    "symbol": "AMD",
    "description": "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. - Common Stock",
    "bidPrice": 92.11
  },
  "MSFT": {
    "assetType": "EQUITY",
    "symbol": "MSFT",
    "description": "Microsoft Corporation - Common Stock",
    "bidPrice": 243.1
  }
}
```

To be able to deserialize the Json, I would have to implement the following DataClass:

```
Public Class DataClass
  Public Property AMD As AMD
  Public Property MSFT As MSFT
End Class

Public Class AMD
  Public Property assetType As String
  Public Property symbol As String
  Public Property description As String
  Public Property bidPrice As Double
End Class

Public Class MSFT
  Public Property assetType As String
  Public Property symbol As String
  Public Property description As String
  Public Property bidPrice As Double
End Class
```

This would work but is absolutely static and does not make any sense, as I would have to implement **a (identical) class for any ticker**, I maybe want to query in the feature.

I would expect to get back a dynamic list so that I could implement the class as following:

```
Public Class DataClass
  Public Property TickerDetails As List(Of TickerDetail)
End Class

Public Class TickerDetail
  Public Property assetType As String
  Public Property symbol As String
  Public Property description As String
  Public Property bidPrice As Double
End Class
```

This way, I would be able to deserialize in a List of TickerDetails and the go thru the list (no matter, which symbols I queried).
But, I can’t change, what I get back over the API...

**Question:

What is the best way to handle this problem?**

Comment: A [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) might do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks for the comments.
I ended up to do it completely different now...
I had further problems with the Ameritrade API:

- Some fields are named with leading numbers (52WkHigh and 52WkLow) and
  vb.net dev's know, that VB.net don't like properties in classes that
  are named with a leading number
- So I had to "patch" the received Json data and change the names on the fly to other names ("52WkHigh" to "dble52WkHigh" and "52WkLow" to "dble52WkLow") to be able to deserialize
  over the data class, what is not nice

Further, I finally need the data (as fast as possible) in a data table and had "a long way to go":
get data -> deserialize to the data class -> walk thru the data class and overtake the data in the data table.
**So.. my new solution (with JObject):**
Note: needs:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

**Code snippets:**

**Create data table in memory:**

```
  Dim dtErgebnis As New DataTable
  Dim drTemp As DataRow
  With dtErgebnis.Columns
    .Add("symbol", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Add("lastPrice", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"))
    .Add("lastSize", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    .Add("quoteTime", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime")) ' Note: is a Long in Json
    ...
 End With
```

**Parse the Json-String and fill the datatable:**
get the data over httpclient (in JsonString)...

```
Dim oJson As JObject = JObject.Parse(JsonString) ' creates children tokens
Dim results As List(Of JToken) = oJson.Children().ToList
 For Each item As JProperty In results
    item.CreateReader()
    drTemp = dtErgebnis.NewRow() ' create a new row to data table in memory
    ' Fill the fields
    drTemp("symbol") = item.Value("symbol")
    drTemp("lastPrice") = item.Value("lastPrice")
    drTemp("lastSize") = item.Value("lastSize")
    drTemp("quoteTime") = GetUTCDateFromTimeStamp(item.Value("quoteTimeInLong")).AddHours(1) ' original Long 
...
'  Add the new row to the  data table
   dtErgebnis.Rows.Add(drTemp)
   ' Save the changes
    dtErgebnis.AcceptChanges()
Next
```

Additional note: The Ameritrade API gives back the time stamps as long (additional hurdle), but I (and I think also you;-) want it as datetime.
Therefore the Long (I think this data type comes from Java/Unix) has to be "translated" to datetime = vb.net function GetUTCDateFromTimeStamp below:

```
  Public Function GetUTCDateFromTimeStamp(TimeStamp As Long) As DateTime
    Static startTime As New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    Return startTime.AddMilliseconds(TimeStamp)
  End Function
```

Additional note:
As I want to have the Swiss time, I add one hour to the UTC time.

So.. this a real good solution for me (exactly for the Ameritrade API).
And.. it's blazing fast... (I get 19 tickers with all fields and show the result (data table) in a data grid).
All together took < 1 Second ("felt" about 500 ms)

Hope this helps somebody...

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class to represent the a generic stock and then use DeserializeObject to deserialize it into a Dictionary(Of String, [classname]) where the Key represents the stock symbol and the value represents the class.

Take a look at this example:

```vb
Public Class Stock
  Public Property assetType As String
  Public Property symbol As String
  Public Property description As String
  Public Property bidPrice As Double
End Class
'...
Dim stocks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Stock))(response)
```

Example: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mbmhe6)

Comment: Hey - thanks for your answer (that seems to work)! In the meantime, I have found a (for my case better) solution that works  (see my own posting). If I had not found my new solution, I would implement yours.